# Show that $a_n$ is monotonic and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have the following sequence $$a_n=\frac{1}{2+3}+\frac{1}{2^2+3^2}+\frac{1}{2^3+3^3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^n+3^n}$$ and I need to show that it is monotonic and bounded.

It is easy to show that the sequence is increasing since $$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}>0$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The sequence is also bounded from below because $a_n \geq a_1=\frac{1}{5}$.

I do not know how to find an upper bound. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Compare with a geometric sum?

Comment: I wanted to bound this by $a_n<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^n}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}$. Is it also correct?

Comment: @Uhans Yes it is correct, my bound was wrong actually  But the idea is the same

Comment: Ok! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The monotony is as you said. The sequence is also bounded from above because, for each $n$ you have
$$
\frac{1}
{{2^n  + 3^n }} \leqslant \frac{1}
{{2^n }}
$$
and therefore
$$
a_n  \leqslant \frac{1}
{2} + \frac{1}
{{2^2 }} +  \cdots \frac{1}
{{2^n }} \leqslant \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}
{{2^n }}}  = 2
$$